# AWS amplify auth How to remove redirect uri

Tags: amazon-web-services, authentication, redirect, aws-amplify

How can I remove a redirect uri using amplify.

Running `amplify auth update` gives no option for removing a redirect uri, there is only a 'add/edit' option. I have tried to look through the documentation but with no success.

Comment: I just found this [issue](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/3895) on github, it might solve my issue. Will report back with the result

Comment: So I solved my problem with the github issue linked above. I ended up ignoring the uri(s) added in amplify since they don't seem to be supported in the aws javascript api. Since I ignore the uris added in the aws amplify api it does not really matter if I cant remove them

Answer (score 13):

While it doesn't seem to be possible to remove redirects using the amplify CLI, you can do it manually by editing the (multiple) `parameters.json` files that amplify creates. Search for the `CallbackURLs` and `LogoutURLs` fields in the `oAuthMetadata` and you can manually delete the sign in/sign out redirects that you no longer want.

Answer (score 1):

there are 2 places where you need to update the signin and signout urls to avoid breaking the backend build:

`aws-exports.js`, which is usually located in the root of your project.

`parameters.json` of the amplify/backend/auth/appname folder

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to:

1. `amplify update auth`
2. select `Add/Edit signin and signout redirect URIs`
3. Modify the uri you want to remove to something like `{your_app_name}://callback_to_remove`
4. Search the files containing `callback_to_remove` in your project and remove the uri.
5. `amplify push`

Answer (score 0):

Modify parameters.json seems not working. Instead, modify cli-inputs.json. It's in the path amplify/backend/ of your folder.
Search for the CallbackURLs and LogoutURLs fields in the oAuthMetadata, and manually edit it.

After that amplify push will work, it will update the local's file: parameters.json and aws-export.js, and also update the Cognito's (backend) side.

By the way, if you use amplify hosting, you should build your frontend(e.g. git push if you link the repo) to sync the confi file for frontend application.

Answer (score -4):

Hi There I am sure you have probably figured it by now or they have recently added this option but in the backend, you can click on the bottom option rewrites and redirects.

[image: Image showing the option for rewrites and redirects]

Comment: This feature does not allow you to do what the OP asked